# Disposing SqlConnection when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm wondering the following code pattern:

```
    static SqlConnection getcon()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=foobar..");
        con.Open();

        // is con Disposed automatically or will it leak and live 
        // forever when exception is thrown?

        throw new Exception("exception");
        return con;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            using (var con = getcon())
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET Column1 = 'test'", con))
            {                   
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch     
        {
        }
    }
```

Is this a safe way to use `SqlConnection` (getting a connection from the `getcon()` method)? Will it be disposed after the function exits when an exception is thrown or will it live forever?

The purpose why I want this `GetCon()` method is to shorten code and wrap the connection creation and opening in one line (`using (var con = getcon())`..)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok! But is the connection disposed even when the exception occurs in the "using" -line, not inside the curly brackets { }?

Comment: To go through all this trouble (and possibly into side-effects and errors) to just simply avoid typing **one line** of code (`conn.Open()` ) seems like a very misguided and premature optimization - don't do it. It's just not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
is con Disposed automatically or will it leak and live orever when exception is thrown?

throw new Exception("exception");
return con;//your code
```

Actually `return con;` line is unreachable. In other words it will never execute here. you're not returning `con` method actually exits by throwing an `Exception`. so your connection will not be cleaned `here`.

When the method exits(by exception) the local variable is out of `Scope` and you have no managed references to the same, so obviously your `con` is subject to `Garbage Collection`.

```
will it leak and live orever when exception is thrown?
```

Answer is no, Garbage collector will take care of reclaiming the memory used by `Connection` and your connection will be closed when `Dispose(true)` is called typically from `Finalizer`.

**Edit**

Assume your get con method doesn't throw any exception and returns a `Connection` and `Exception` is thrown as below

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var con = getcon())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET Column1 = 'test'", con))
{
    throw new Exception("Oops");//Throw excception somewhere here             
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Above code will guarantee cleanup when an Exception is thrown since you wrapped `con` in `using` statement.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The way you have written you getcon method (I assume you did it specifically to test something), con will be freed the moment exception is thrown. Since `return con;' is after exception you are throwing, it will never be returned to the calling code and will be freed as soon as getcon exits (for going out of scope).

Answer (score 1):

I think jaadooviewer's answer is correct, but it seems like you could avoid the question entirely by using a try/catch block in the getcon method.

```
try
{
    SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection("...");
    con.Open();
    if (/*condition*/)
        throw new Exception("Exception Condition Satisfied");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Dispose();
    throw ex;
}
return con;
```

Comment: The primary question here is does the Using -block extend it's tentacles inside the `getcon()` method or not

Comment: @Jaska - Yes.  `getcon()` is called within your using block, so it is "within" the block, so to speak.

Comment: You likely would want to do `catch (Execption)` combined with `throw;` so you don't loose the stack trace. (also `Dispose()` implicitly calls `Close()` for a `SqlConnection` so you don't need to call it in the catch block)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first comment.  Thanks for the clarification on the second.